# spray: custom onSuccess directive

Tags: scala, spray

I have many routes with code like

```
onSuccess(Future(x.unsafePerformIO))(_.fold(f, complete(_)))
```

where `x` is `IO[A \/ B]` from scalaz. I want to extract this into custom directive like

```
def handleFutureIO[A, B](ioab: IO[A \/ B])(handleLeft: A => Route) = 
  onSuccess(Future(ioab.unsafePerformIO))(_.fold(handleLeft, complete(_))`
```

Probably I need some magnet.

can somebody help me implement this?

Comment: What goes wrong when you try exactly what you posted there? You will need to take an `implicit B => CompletionMagnet`, but in general the compiler error messages are what guides you to what implicits are needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def forkIOHandleLeft[A, B](ioab: IO[A \/ B])(handleLeft: A => Route)(implicit marshaller: B => ToResponseMarshallable) = 
  onSuccess(Future(ioab.unsafePerformIO))(_.fold(handleLeft, complete(_)))
```